# Show TimeField value without seconds - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm displaying a selectbox with hours in it. This hours are fixed and coming from db. For this I used `models.TimeField` in `models.py`. Now in `html` page these hours are shown like `14:00:00`. I want to remove seconds. Here are my codes:

`models.py`:

```
class MeetingHour(models.Model):
    hour = models.TimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.hour)
```

`html`:

```
<select>
{% for meetinghour in meetinghours %}
  <option value="{{meetinghour}}">{{meetinghour}}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`|time`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#time):

```
<option value="{{ meetinghour }}">{{ meetinghour.hour|time:"H:i" }}</option>
```

Comment: Thank you, friend, so much.

Comment: Man, hello, have a good day. Can you check please my this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156491/django-form-save-is-not-creating-modelform ? Last days my question reach very few people, and can't tag someone. Please, help me.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to format the relevant tag in your template using the time format, so something like this...

```
<option value="{{meetinghour}}">{{meetinghour|time:"H:i"}}</option>
```

Comment: Not a correct answer, man, but thank you again. It must be: ```<option value="{{ meetinghour }}">{{ meetinghour.hour|time:"H:i" }}</option>```